# I have bought a ipad 2 32gb wifi and 3g it came with ios 4.3.5. how would i jailbreak it?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ipad

i have seen many people among my friends who have **jailbroken** their **ipad 1**. I have just bought an **ipad 2** yesterday and wish to do the same . how would i jailbreak it i have also tried downloading an ios 4.3.3 firmware

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you are running iOS 5.0.1 (or if you update to iOS 5.0.1 through iTunes), you can use Absinthe to JailBreak your iPad 2. Go to http://greenpois0n.com/ and look for the "JailBreak iOS 5.0.1" table on the right of the page. Choose your download, and enjoy! It's really easy and intuitive to JailBreak with Absinthe. For further reference, you can always check out http://www.jailbrea.kr/ for the latest updates and info. Note that Absinthe is only for the iPhone 4S and iPad 2 running iOS 5.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can only jailbreak iPad 2 till 4.3.3. So your version isn't supported by any of the available jailbreak methods at this moment...

Comment: You should check out Absinthe on http://greenpois0n.com. It's for JailBreaking Apple devices with A5 processors on iOS 5.0.1. It was released quite recently.

Comment: Yes, I know, but you couldn't jailbreak an A5 based device on December 5th :)

Comment: I totally forgot to check the date on the question/answer. My bad. There aren't enough JailBreaking questions on here.